# RDP - keystroke forwarding

Tags: remote-desktop

I'm using multiple pulpits to work effectively on Windows (VirtuaWin). To switch between pulpits I'm using defined keystrokes - `Ctrl+Alt+Fn` to switch to n-th pulpit.

I like to use RDP in fullscreen on one of pulpits. Unfortunately when I want to switch to another pulpit I have to switch fullscreen RDP session to window mode `Ctrl+Alt+Break` and then switch to another pulpit `Ctrl+Alt+Fn`.

Is it possible to forward somehow panel switching keystrokes from within RDP sesion to host OS? It is possible to do it by some manipulations just on host OS?